# Count Down to Christmas with Joda-Time

Tags: java, datetime, time, jodatime, countdown

I am trying to implement [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to count down to Christmas, but so far I'm struck. I tried java.util.Date and most StackOverflow questions and answers suggested to use Joda-Time. But I can't get it working. Some codes give different answers.

Here are some codes I tried,

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime christmas = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25, 8, 0, 0, 0);
Days daysToChristmas = Days.daysBetween(today, christmas); 
System.out.println(daysToChristmas.toString());
```

And this prints **P187D** as answer.

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(DateTime.now());
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0 ,0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
System.out.println("Seconds " + period.getSeconds());
System.out.println("Minutes " + period.getMinutes());
System.out.println("Hours " + period.getHours());
System.out.println("Days " + period.getDays());
```

And this prints following result,

```
Seconds 36
Minutes 21
Hours 7
Days 4
```

Where I went wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the first code?

Comment: It prints P187D. How do I get Days, hours, minutes and seconds from that object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be using a `Period` in order to determine the number of months/days/etc involved:

```
Period period = new Period(start, end);
```

Converting an `Interval` to a period would have been fine too, but parameterless overload includes *all* period units - and you weren't printing out the months.

Now if you *only* want days, hours, minutes, seconds then you need to create an appropriate `PeriodType`, e.g.

```
PeriodType periodType = PeriodType.dayTime().withMillisRemoved();
Period period = new Period(start, end, periodType);
```

Then you can ask for those individual fields, and all should be well.

(You could actually use just `dayTime()`, given that the millis won't interfere with anything else.)

So you can either build your period directly from the `start` and `end` as above, or if you want to keep the `Interval`, you can use:

```
Period period = interval.toPeriod(periodType);
```

Comment: I cannot believe I'm saying this to you of all people, but… I believe you are incorrect about that first sentence. The [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class does indeed understand beginning and ending DateTime objects. I suspect you confused Interval with the [`Duration`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) class. In Joda-Time, a Duration is a length of time in milliseconds, without a position on the timeline. The Question's example code's use of Interval is correct, if unnecessary.

Comment: @BasilBourque: You're definitely right that I was getting confused with duration. `Interval` is to my mind still *logically* the wrong type as it's documented to be the time between two *instants*, which means there should be no chronology involved - however `Interval` also stores a `Chronology`, so you can indeed get back the appropriate end points as `DateTime` values. I think it's probably best to just scrub the first couple of sentences, which I'll do now :)

Comment: @BasilBourque: I decided to restructure things a bit more, in the end. Thanks so much for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

The first code prints **P187D**, in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

The second code prints only 4 days because you're missing the months (`period.getMonths()`).

Comment: Well, is there a way to convert months to dates, I don't need months, I just need days.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code.

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int seconds=Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds();

int noOfDays=seconds/(24*60*60);
int noOfHours=(seconds%(24*60*60))/(60*60);
int noOfMinutes=((seconds%(24*60*60))%(60*60))/60;
int noSec=((seconds%(24*60*60))%(60*60))%60;

System.out.println("Time Left For christmas");
System.out.println("Days Left="+noOfDays+" Hours="+noOfHours+" Minutes="+noOfMinutes+" Seconds="+noSec);
```