# Android days left

Tags: java, android, time

I need to do the `CountDown Days` from one date to the second date

e.g

`CURRENT_DATE:3/1/2013`  `NEXT_DATE:21/01/2013`

then it displays ::`17 DAYS LEFT`

I implemented code like these

```
String inputDateString = "01/22/2013";
Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calNext = Calendar.getInstance();
calNext.setTime(new Date(inputDateString)); 

if(calNext.after(calCurr)) 
{
    long timeDiff = calNext.getTimeInMillis() - calCurr.getTimeInMillis();
    int daysLeft = (int) (timeDiff/DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
    dni.setText("Days Left: "+daysLeft);
}
else
{
    long timeDiff = calCurr.getTimeInMillis() - calNext.getTimeInMillis();
    timeDiff = DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS - timeDiff;
    int daysLeft = (int) (timeDiff/DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

Is there a better way to do achieve these?

Comment: Use JodaTime, it's kind of simple stuff with such library ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026136/find-remaining-day-and-time-using-jodatime

Comment: See this [question about countdown to Christmas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11118262/642706), using Joda-Time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Calendar`'s Methods:

```
String inputDateString = "01/22/2013";
Calendar calCurr = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
day.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(inputDateString));
if(day.after(calCurr)){
               System.out.println("Days Left: " + (day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) -(calCurr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))) );
}
```

Output: Days Left: 17

And to increment the year by 1 , you could use Calendar.add() method

```
        day.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: You use get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) difference between two dates. I returns wrong amount of days when the difference is more than 1 month.

Comment: Yes, this only works for days within the same month. If you try 8 (October) - 30 (September), this will return -22 which is a wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries to convert date to `n days` format:

- [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)
- [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: How can I do so that it will be 17 days and sets up the date again? So to 21/01/2014.

Answer (score 1):

I use this class

```
import android.text.format.DateUtils;

import java.util.Date;

import static android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE;
import static android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE;
import static android.text.format.DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR;
import static android.text.format.DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;

/**
 * Utilities for dealing with dates and times
 */
public class TimeUtils {

    /**
     * Get relative time for date
     *
     * @param date
     * @return relative time
     */
    public static CharSequence getRelativeTime(final Date date) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (Math.abs(now - date.getTime()) > 60000)
            return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.getTime(), now,
                    MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
                    | FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE);
        else
            return "Just now";
    }
}
```

`TimeUtils.getRelativeTime(date)` returns text like
Just now,
2 min. ago,
2 hours ago,
2 days ago,
04.11.2013

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( 
    LocalDate.now() , 
    LocalDate.of( 2013 , Month.JANUARY , 21 ) 
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Determine your dates.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2013 , Month.JANUARY , 3 ) ;  // 3/1/2013
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2013 , Month.JANUARY , 21 ) ; // 21/01/2013
```

### Today’s date

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Or `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to indicate explicitly that you want the JVM’s current default time zone. Beware of that default changing *during* runtime.
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

### Elapsed days

The [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) calculates elapsed time in various granularity.

```
long daysElapsed = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

I searched this code on internet, but didn't manage to find. Though I'm replying late, this will be useful piece of code.

```
public static String getTimeLeft(String date) { // dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    String[] DateSplit = date.split("-");
    int month = Integer.parseInt(DateSplit[1]) - 1, // if month is november  then subtract by 1
    year = Integer.parseInt(DateSplit[0]), day = Integer
            .parseInt(DateSplit[2]), hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0;
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int sec = second - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND), min = minute
            - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE), hr = hour
            - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), dy = day
            - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE), mnth = month
            - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), daysinmnth = 32 - dy;

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();

    end.set(year, month, day);

    if (mnth != 0) {
        if (dy != 0) {
            if (sec < 0) {
                sec = (sec + 60) % 60;
                min--;
            }
            if (min < 0) {
                min = (min + 60) % 60;
                hr--;
            }
            if (hr < 0) {
                hr = (hr + 24) % 24;
                dy--;
            }
            if (dy < 0) {
                dy = (dy + daysinmnth) % daysinmnth;
                mnth--;
            }
            if (mnth < 0) {
                mnth = (mnth + 12) % 12;
            }
        }
    }

    String hrtext = (hr == 1) ? "hour" : "hours", dytext = (dy == 1) ? "day"
            : "days", mnthtext = (mnth == 1) ? "month" : "months";

    if (now.after(end)) {
        return "";
    } else {
        String months = "", days = "", hours = "";
        months = (mnth > 0) ? mnth + " " + mnthtext : "";
        if (mnth <= 0) {
            days = (dy > 0) ? dy + " " + dytext : "";
            if (dy <= 0) {
                hours = (hr > 0) ? hr + " " + hrtext : "";
            }
        }
        //Log.d("DATE", months + " 1 " + days + " 2 " + hours);
        return months + days + hours;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers ignore time zone, which may be crucial depending on how accurate you want your countdown. If you do not specify a time zone, you get the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)'s default.

The java.util.Date & .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) or the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).

A bit of code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) 2.3, untested (off the top of my head). Search StackOverflow for *many* more examples.

```
String input = "01/22/2013";
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" ).withZone( timeZone );
DateTime future = formatterInput.parseDateTime( input );

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );

int days = Days.daysBetween( now, future ).getDays();
Interval interval = new Interval( now, future );
Period period = new Period( interval );
```

Do some `System.out.println` calls for those variables and be amazed.

The string format you'll see is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can create other formats as well.